# Reading an ASCII file with fstream

Tags: c++

Have an ASCII text file with some integer numbers in it, each separated by a space, and sometimes the numbers go on to a new line. For example:

```
// my_file.txt
23 45 973 49
44 1032 33 99
43 8 4 90824
```

I want to read 100 of these numbers into an array of "ints". Thus far, I have the following code:

```
int x[100];
fstream file_in("my_file.txt", ios::in);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    file_in >> x[i];
}
```

However, I now want to do a couple of other things that I am not sure about.

1. What if I want to just read the entire file in, without having to go through the loop? If this was binary data, I know that I can just write `file_in.read((char*)&x[0], 100 * sizeof(int))`. But how can I do this with an ASCII file?
2. What if I want to skip the first 3 numbers in the file, and start reading from the fourth? Again, if this was binary data, I could just use `file_in.seekg(3 * sizeof(char))`. But I don't know how to skip in an ASCII file.

Comment: Please have a nice try and error session with the debugger (Also: do not forget to check the stream state)

Comment: Any method you use is going to use a loop, at some level. Maybe you're not using a loop in your own code, but the code you call into will be. What is your problem with loops?

Comment: Well normally with binary code, I could just set an address to read from, and the number of bytes to read, and it will just read the file all in one. In this case, it would not seem very elegant to loop through and load each byte individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No raw loops!

Reading the entire file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("data.txt");
    std::vector<int> v(std::istream_iterator<int>(f), {});
```

Skipping over the first three:

```
   v.erase(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3);
```

Comment: What if `v` needs to be initialized beyond the scope of the file being opened? How can you replace the last line to instead place the return of the iterator into an already created vector?

Comment: I'm going to add an edit to address my question, but please change it to something more elegant if possible

Comment: @Anonymous: That's not hard: `std::vector<int> v; { std::ifstream f("data.txt"); v.assign(std::istream_iterator<int>(f), {}); }`